# Intended meaning of "Schrottsemmel"

Tags: joke

In the section "Hohlspiegel" of der Spiegel is the following:

> Schrottsemmel
>
> 3 Stück 0,99 Euro
>
> (Aus der Bäckerei-Werbung in der *Südwest Presse*)

I'm guessing it must be funny because "Schrottsemmel" is a typo, since "Schrott" means scrap metal. But what is actually intended?

Comment: It's a typo which produces a weird new word. Literally it can be taken as "scrap (metal) bun". The first thing I actually thought of though was a really worn down car; "Semmel" as in *"die Strasse langsemmeln"*, "Semmel" = "wheels"/"vehicle", also see "Möhre", "Kiste"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it should be [Schrot](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrot_%28Getreide%29) instead of Schrott.

Comment: Note that Schrott is also a mildly colloquial term for goods that are defective or of poor quality.